# Elementary OS on Ubuntu 14

Tags: elementary

I have just installed Ubuntu 14 and I am loving the feel of it.

I first intended to install Elementary OS but failed to do so.

I then followed the stept from: http://tuxdiary.com/2015/06/27/install-pantheon-desktop-ubuntu/

To get a Elementary on my Ubuntu 14.

It said I had to log out and log in on elemetary but there is no option to chose the Pantheon. I can only give in my password and thats it. Now I have all kinds of elemetary os packages installed and none working.

Does this slow down my device and how can I undo the changes I made?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having the unnecessary packages from the Elementary PPA installed on your system shouldn't slow down your system, if the Elementary packages you installed are not being used as would be the case if you can't login on Elementary because there is no option to choose Pantheon. To remove the Elementary packages you installed from the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get remove elementary-* pantheon-* plymouth-theme-elementary* syslinux-themes-elementary maya-calendar
sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:elementary-os/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get autoremove
```